# Duplicate 'System.SerializableAttribute' attribute when "paste xml as classes" for the same root tag

Tags: c#, xml

Let's say I have 2 XML with the same root, Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>   
</catalog>
```

and in second XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <author id="23">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <age>45</age>
   </author>
   <author id="26">
      <author>Ali</author>
      <age>65</age>
   </author>       
</catalog>
```

When I want to deserialize it using Visual Studio, I will create a class for each XML, copy the XML content and paste special > "paste XML as classes".

Then, I will be getting a lot of code generated for me like below:

```
// NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class catalog
    {

        private catalogBook[] bookField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("book")]
        public catalogBook[] book
        {
            get
            {
                return this.bookField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.bookField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class catalogBook
    {

        private string authorField;

        private string titleField;

        private string genreField;

        private decimal priceField;

        private System.DateTime publish_dateField;

        private string descriptionField;

        private string idField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string author
        {
            get
            {
                return this.authorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.authorField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string title
        {
            get
            {
                return this.titleField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.titleField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string genre
        {
            get
            {
                return this.genreField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.genreField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal price
        {
            get
            {
                return this.priceField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.priceField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
        public System.DateTime publish_date
        {
            get
            {
                return this.publish_dateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.publish_dateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string description
        {
            get
            {
                return this.descriptionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.descriptionField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I repeat the same step for the second XML, I will get an error in these lines:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
```

The error is `Duplicate 'System.SerializableAttribute' attribute`

My question is how to do fix this problem when my XML file has the same ROOT tag? In this case, the root tag is `catalog`

Comment: Note: the paste XML as classes option is very convenient, but the generated C# is pretty horrid. The same thing can be represented by much cleaner hand-written types if you prefer, but: if that isn't important, don't worry about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, what is happening is that you have two `partial class catalog` definitions in the same c# namespace. That means they are **combined**. Two choices:

1. (Preferred) put them in different c# namespaces - suitably named for whatever the difference is between their uses
2. Leave them where they are, but rename the types themselves, including any other types (not just the root)

Alternatively, you could have a single `Catalog` type that has containers for both books and authors, if that is more useful. But you'd have to write the type manually. It would probably be about 10-15 lines of code to do so (replacing *all* of the generated code)

Comment: But then I have like 20 XML files. I think I will just let Visual Studio auto generate the code. Thanks, with different namespace, no more error now.